# Determining size of identical adjacents values in a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector made of 0 and 1. It refers to hourly met data with 0 = no rain, 1 = rain event during the corresponding hour.

The objective is to determine the duration of all rain events i.e. the length of each block of 1s in the vector.

Is there anything better than a loop screening all values and neigthbours 1 by 1.

Thanks in advance for your help.
All the best,
Vincent

Comment: I really think you are going to like the function `rle`.

Comment: @joran, that's definitely answer-worthy.

Comment: @dbaupp The question has no code to work with, and when my only answer is to name a function, I tend to simply leave a comment and let others spend the time to construct more elaborate answers.

Comment: @joran you're right, a bit of code in my question would have been more appropriate. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @joran suggests, `rle` is what you want.

```
hourly.rain <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
with(rle(hourly.rain), lengths[values == 1])
#[1] 2 1 2
```

If you want to observe an inter-event time, say 2 hours, (i.e., events separated by 2 hours or less are considered the same event), you can also use `rle` to replace those 0s within the inter-event period with 1s.

```
inter.event <- 2
hourly.rain <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)
with(rle(hourly.rain), {
     fwd.lag <- c(head(values, -1), 1)
     bkwd.lag <- c(1, tail(values, -1))
     replace.vals <- values == 0 & lengths <= inter.event & fwd.lag == bkwd.lag
     rep(replace(values, replace.vals, 1) , lengths)
})
# [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: @Joran : indeed I start to like this rle function

Comment: @ Matthew Thanks a lot for your clear answer. You even anticipated my needs! All the best, Vincent

Comment: @allardvinc you're welcome. please remember to accept the answer so the question is resolved. Thanks.